# ListBox with rows from table

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Is it possible to have a list-box filled with rows from table? That it would look like similarly to grid. The column would be properly wide and so on..

Comment: have you tried anything? if then add your snippet to get correction and suggestion

Comment: Have you looked at Datagrid? It may be more along the lines of what you want.

Comment: I'm trying to do this with listview. GridView is not what I'm looking for. But thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w67sdsex%28v=vs.100%29.aspx :)

```
    List<string> items = new List<string>();
    foreach (DataRow dataRow in theDataTable.Rows)
    {
            items.Add(dataRow["column1"].ToString() + " " + dataRow["column2"].ToString();
    }
    listBox1.DataSource = items;
```

Comment: Hmm, in that case you will get something like:

        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataRow dataRow in theDataTable.Rows)
        {
                items.Add(dataRow["column1"].ToString() + " " + dataRow["column2"].ToString();
        }
        listBox1.DataSource = items;

Comment: Well another option would be is that you stitch the data together in the query / database so you get 1 column with exactly the data you want. Then you can go for the first option again.